# Bootstrap pull-right pushes the table outside fixed width container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

When I have a `col-xs-6` with `pull-right` containing a table extending 100% with `text-nowrap` class that stretches the cell beyond `col-xs-6` it flows to right going out of the fixed width container. I wish it should flow towards *left* and have the right border aligned. Is this possible?

The best way to understand the problem is look at this code.

[PROBLEM showcase on bootply](http://www.bootply.com/rjA1rQgoSA)

I am pasting the code here as well just in case the link isn't working (it needs bootstrap 3)

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="width:400px; background:#CCC;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <table border="1" width="100%">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Item 1</td>
                        <td class="text-right">420.00</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 pull-right">
            <table border="1" width="100%">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="text-nowrap">Sub Total with long text</td>
                        <td class="text-right">420.00</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Total</td>
                        <td class="text-right">420.00</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Update:** My container needs to be of exactly of 400px, changing the container size is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be with `text-nowrap` if you remove this class the text comes back inside the table but I can see the text then goes onto multiple lines.

Here is the code that fixed it for me:

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="width:450px; background:#CCC;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <table border="1" width="100%">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Item 1</td>
                        <td class="text-right">420.00</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 pull-right">
            <table border="1" width="100%">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="text-nowrap">Sub Total with long text</td>
                        <td class="text-right">420.00</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Total</td>
                        <td class="text-right">420.00</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I simply made your table 50px bigger, hopefully your table doesn't need to be exactly 400px and if you don't making 50px bigger will fix the problem. :P

Best of luck :)

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, but for the matter of fact, my container/table needs to be of exactly of 400px (it is a printable layout).

Comment: Yes, I am using bootstrap 3+

Comment: Hmmm.. give me 2 minutes to replicate this on my PC